# Dropdown with animation with full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I Have created simple dropdown menu, where sub-menu is full width
jsFiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".drop").hide();
    $(".link-1").mouseenter(function(){
            $('.link-1-drop').slideDown("fast");
    });
    $(".link-1").mouseleave(function(){
            $('.link-1-drop').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/814z6eL5/2/

As both are different DIVs , when we mouse out to link and mouse enter to div container ,container div slides up.

Is there any way to keep the drop-down div open while move mouse to container?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the div inside the `li` so when you hover over the container you are still hovering over the `li`. You can then use `position:absolute;` on the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/814z6eL5/4/

Answer (score 2):

wrap the both `li` and `slide` in one element and assign event to wrapper element.
Check in jsFiddle code here

[Mouseenter code](https://jsfiddle.net/814z6eL5/3/)

Comment: when you put your mouse beside that `li`, it will still trigger `$(".link-1")` to do `mouseenter`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition to see if the `.link-1-drop` is hovered. And if YES then do not close it, if NO , close it ( when leaving the `link1`)

See below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop").hide();
  $(".link-1").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.link-1-drop').slideDown("fast");
  });

  $(".link-1").mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$('.link-1-drop').is(':hover')) {
        $('.link-1-drop').slideUp("fast");
      }
    }, 100);
  });

});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:20px
}
.drop{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="link-1">Link 1</li>
</ul>
<div class="link-1-drop drop">
  drop down content
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to that your code take effect without putting your div inside the Main-div

just make sur the li has same hight as the div container and check when you leave the li if the mouse hover the drop div or not as below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".drop").hide();
    
    $(".link-1 ").mouseenter(function(){
            $('.link-1-drop').slideDown("fast");
    });
    
    $(".link-1").mouseleave(function(){
     if($(".link-1-drop:not(:hover)").length>0)
            $('.link-1-drop').slideUp("fast");
    });
    
    $(".link-1-drop").mouseleave(function(){
     if($(".link-1:not(:hover)").length>0)
            $('.link-1-drop').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*commented height to match li height */
  /* height:20px;*/
}
.drop{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #0ff;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="link-1">Link 1</li>
</ul>
<div class="link-1-drop drop">
  drop down content
</div>
```

Otherwise and better , just put your drop div inside the li , and make css change by adding to

```
.drop {
  ...
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

As bellow Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop").hide();
  $(".link-1 ").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.link-1-drop').slideDown("fast");
  });
  $(".link-1").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.link-1-drop').slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 20px
}

.drop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #0ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="link-1">Link 1
    <div class="link-1-drop drop">
      drop down content
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```